# how to return to underlying script from tail -f

Tags: ksh, aix

I have a `ksh` script, in which I use `tail -f` to view a log file.

How can I terminate the `tail` process, and continue executing the underlying script?

I am running it on AIX 7.1.
---------------------------------------------edit-----------------------------------
according to Gilles's answer, I tried this in my script:

```
trap 'echo "tail process terminated!"' 2
tail -f mylog.log
trap - 2
```

Now after tail command get executed, then I press CTRL+C, the tail process was killed, and my script continue to run. But the new problem is , when I press CTRL+C again, my script will not exit. Any one can help ?

Comment: How does the script know when to stop `tail`ing?

Comment: @richard let the user to stop the `tail`, press some special key for example

Comment: look at @flup's  answer. You will have to add something to read the key, before the kill (there it says "do some other stuff").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of `tail -f` is to run forever until explicitly killed, so you'll have to arrange to kill it.

If there is some logic that determines when the `tail` process is to be killed, obtain the process ID of `tail` and arrange to trigger its killing when desired. For example, if you want to kill it after a minute:

```
tail -f file.log &
tail_pid=$!
sleep 60
kill $tail_pid
do_more_stuff
```

If you want to terminate `tail` but not the shell script when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, [trap](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.osdevice/korn_shell_spec_builtin_cmd_desc.htm?lang=en) the [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_(POSIX)#SIGINT) signal. You need to set the trap to a non-empty string (any non-empty value will do, even a space) since an empty string would cause SIGINT to be ignored by the `tail` subprocess as well as by the calling shell.

```
trap : INT       # set a signal handler for SIGINT that does nothing
tail -f file.log
do_more_stuff    # executed when tail is killed, e.g. by the user pressing Ctrl+C
trap - INT       # reset SIGINT to killing the script
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't background the `tail` command in your script, the shell will wait for it to exit, which will never happen.

If you have other work to do, after which you want to kill the `tail` command, you can

```
tail -f logfile &
tailpid=$!
...do some other stuff...
kill $tailpid
...carry on...
```